# Home directory incorrect

Tags: macos, terminal

Somehow my home directory got changed to the linux default instead of the Mac default. When I launch a new terminal I get:

```
Last login: Wed Mar 26 20:49:25 on ttys001
No home directory: /home/{user}
{host}:/ {user}$ pwd
/
```

How do I change it back to `/Users/{user}`?

Answer (score 1):

Check the shell environment variables ( and terminal.app preferences)
Somewhere something has been changed. 
It could be in one of the many possible files that Bash and family read on launch/ login to set env variables. 
Also make sure you're logged in to OSX as the correct user.

Comment: It fixed itself via some magic over night, but thanks for the answer.